# ld fails to find openssl, even though its present

Tags: r, ld, rcurl

I am trying to install RCurl in R 3.2.0 in RHEL 5.

```
install.packages("RCurl")
```

At the end it failed because

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/home/gowthan/Downloads/R-3.2.0/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o RCurl.so base64.o curl.o curlInit.o curl_base64.o enums.o json.o memoryManagement.o myUTF8.o -L/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-5R4zB/workspace/build/Curl/Curl-7.18.1.155.6782/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/curl/install/lib -lcurl -L/opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Fbopenssl/Fbopenssl-0.0.4.504.7765/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib -lfbopenssl -L/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-5R4zB/workspace/build/Curl/Curl-7.18.1.155.6782/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/tmp/brazil-path/[Openssl]lib.libfarm/lib -L/local/p4clients/pkgbuild-k5Vrj/workspace/build/Libxml2/Libxml2-2.7.8.334.176/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/libxml2/install/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm -L/home/gowthan/Downloads/R-3.2.0/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfbopenssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RCurl.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package \u2018RCurl\u2019
```

The line it fails is : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfbopenssl. But, I have openssl at /usr/bin/openssl. How do I make 'ld' use it?

Regarding openssl-devel, yum install openssl-devel says that I already have the latest package. But "where openssl-devel" says that its not found! Is something wrong here?

Is fbopenssl same as openssl?